What is actually temperature in case of solids and liquids?
We know that temperature in case of ideal gases is caused due to the translational component of the velocity, which causes pressure and then we define temperature according to $pV=nRT$.
But for solids and liquids, how is temperature defined because here there is no translational motion of particles.

Atoms in solids and liquids most definitely do move, so I'm not clear what you are asking.

In solids and liquids, the motion is just vibration right? So a solid can't exert pressure like a gas. In that case how is temperature defined?

temperature is whatever the thermometer measures, this is no different from saying that time is what a clock measures and distance is what a stick (ruler) measures.

Temperature is defined as the average kinetic energy of all the particles in the system. we can measure temperature by using the equation:
$P$ $= \frac{\rho C_{rms}^{2}}{3}$
where $C_{rms}$ $= \sqrt{\frac{3K_{b}T}{m}}$
where $m$ is the mass of a particle of the gas
so we get the equation for temperature to be :
$T$ $=\frac{Pm}{\rho K_{b}}$
But for solids and liquids, how is temperature defined because here there is 
no translational motion of particles.

in the case of solids and liquids there exists Lattice vibrations in
solids and molecular vibrations in liquids which are accountable for the
Temperature.
